# AWS EKS: Assign multiple Service Accounts to Deployment\Pod

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubeless

I'm using Kubeless on AWS EKS. While installing Kubeless, the installation has a [manifest](https://github.com/kubeless/kubeless/releases/download/v1.0.6/kubeless-v1.0.6.yaml) which has some CRDs and a deployment object. The deployment object has already a Service Account attached. I have created another [Service Account](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/introducing-fine-grained-iam-roles-service-accounts/) **in the `kube-system` namespace**, which has some AWS IAM roles attached. I also want to attach this newly created Service Account used for IAM roles to the Kubeless deployment object by modifying the Kubeless manifest file.

I want to have 2 Service Accounts attached to the deployment object: One that comes with Kubeless and other for AWS IAM. Any help would appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 17):

This is not possible. If you look at the [API documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.11/#pod-v1-core) for `PodSpec v1 core` you can see that serviceAccountName expects a `string` not an `array` or `object`. This is because using a ServiceAccount resource creates a 1:1 relationship between your pod and [authentication](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/) against the API server.

You will either need to:

1. Diversify your workload into multiple pods. Which with you can apply different service accounts.
2. Combine your service account capabilities into a single account and apply it exclusively to this pod.

I recommend #2.

Comment: This is so dumb. This completely rails against Google's least privilege recommendations.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree. Considering what I described in 1 above correlates more with Least Privilege than what is requested in the original question.